# How to prevent Gnus from creating a `~/News` directory?

Tags: gnus, spacemacs

I'm using Spacemacs on Debian Linux.  Each time I start Gnus with `SPC a g`, it creates a folder `~/News` in my home directory.  I don't see the point in this, as I only use Gnus to read news via NNTP.

What is this folder good for, and how can I prevent Gnus from creating it?

Comment: FWIW, all Gnus files/directories derive from the variable `gnus-home-directory`, so just setting this to, say, `user-emacs-directory` will move all Gnus files to a less central/intrusive location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My ~/News/ folder holds (at least) drafts, cache, score-files, and the file "suppression" containing gnus-dup-list.

I think you can [configure Gnus to put the folder somewhere else](https://superuser.com/a/519687), but some of the things stored there are integral parts of a news reader, so I don't think you can do without it completely.

Comment: thanks. probably mine is empty because i apparently don't use Gnus to its full potential yet ;)